# How do I delete DenyAllOutBound in azure vm and database?

Tags: azure

How do I delete DenyAllOutBound rule in azure vm and database.

I am trying to connect to azure sql databse from azure machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with the assumption that you meant to ask how to delete the DenyAllOutBound rules in a Network Security Group - unfortunately [you can't do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview#default-security-rules:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20remove%20the%20default%20rules%2C%20but%20you%20can%20override%20them%20by%20creating%20rules%20with%20higher%20priorities.). The DenyAllOutBound rules in a Network Security Group is basically a default rule added by Azure.

What you should do instead is to create a custom higher priority rule (the lower the number, the higher the priority) that will overwrite the default rules. Custom rules are only allowed to have priority numbers from 100 to 4096.

E.g. For the rules below, you'd need to create a new one with a priority of 4096 or below, with your requirements.

[image]

Comment: not working bro what is going on I NEED connection man

Comment: can you provide screenshots of your current configuration?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DutZC.png